# What's the difference between initdb /usr/local/var/[db] and createdb [db]

Tags: postgresql

I am starting to use PostgreSQL and I am confused about the two ways to create a database. When I installed it the first time, the instructions said I have to create a default database with `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres` When I lookup my databases, I can see that I have a database called postgres. Now I am able to create a database with two other commands whereas the former is the command line script and the latter the SQL command. In the case of a "postgres" called database it would be:

- `createdb postgres`
- `CREATE DATABASE postgres`

Both are setting up a database in my list of databases. When I try to create another database with `initdb /usr/local/var/[someDbName]` though, it doesn't appear in my list of databases. So what's the difference between initdb and createdb then?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`initdb` is **not** used to create a "new database".

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/creating-cluster.html) you need it to create a "cluster" or "data directory" which then stores databases created with `create database`.

Quote from the manual:

> Before you can do anything, you must initialize a database storage area on disk. We call this a database cluster. (The SQL standard uses the term catalog cluster.) A database cluster is a collection of databases that is managed by a single instance of a running database server
>
> [...]
>
> In file system terms, a database cluster is a single directory under which all data will be stored. We call this the data directory or data area

In short: `initdb` creates the necessary directory layout on the harddisk to be able to create and manage databases.

It's a necessary part of the *installation* process of a Postgres server.

Comment: So initdb is just a way of grouping databases? Sorry for the question, there are so many how-toes out there which say initdb creates a database.

Comment: Yes and no. `initdb` is needed to **initialize** the physical storage of databases. Consider it a part of the installation process, not a part of the "daily work". Any "how to" that says `initdb` creates a "database" is wrong

Comment: There is an implied hierarchy: host -> cluster[] -> database[] -> schema[] -> table[] -> column[] ; so you need a hostmachine to create a cluster(duh!), and you need a cluster to create a database, etc. [oops, that was intended for the OP]

Comment: For example, when you install Postgres with Homebrew, it comes with nothing and you cannot create any database before you actually create the catalog with `initdb` https://gist.github.com/lxneng/741932